# Delete ManyToManyField if "items" was empty

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have Order Section and my models are like this :

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_added = jmodels.jDateField(auto_now=True)
    date_ordered = jmodels.jDateField(null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='quantity')

class Order(models.Model):
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    is_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem, related_name='item')
    date_ordered = jmodels.jDateField(auto_now=True,null=True)
    created_on_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)

    def get_cart_items(self):
        return self.items.all()

    def get_cart_total(self):         
        return sum([item.quantity*item.product.price for item in self.items.all()])
```

My problem is that when in cart I delete all Items, and Items become empty, but still Order exist in my database. I want the whole of order would delete if Items was empty.

Comment: Why are you using a `ManyToManyField` here? Shouldn't `OrderItem` have a `ForeignKey` to `Order`, after which your problem is as simple as adding a `on_delete=models.CASCADE` and simply deleting `Order`?

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: use signal m2m_changed on Order

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Order)
def m2m_change_order(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not instance.items.exist():
        instance.delete()
```

It will self checking and self-destruct

Option 2: use signal post_save OrderItem

On model OrderItem, set a post_save trigger as below

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

@receiver(post_save, sender=OrderItem)
def post_save_order_item(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    order_list = Order.objects.filter(items=None)
    for order in order_list:
        order.delete()
```

Basically it will check in Order table to find any Order without items, every time an OrderItem is deleted

Comment: Thanks for answering, option 2 doesn't work,

Comment: and option 1 has error : name 'Order' is not defined (cant find Order)